# How does twiends check if you have liked a fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Twiends is a website which allows you to follow other fan pages and gives you credit for liking a page.

Now what I dont understand is how do they check if you have liked a fan page. They use something like fql to get that. Does anyone know how its done or any links to doing the similar. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how Twiends was doing it but obviously giving the users "credits" to like pages that they may not even visit is not ethically right.

Not sure if it's also illegal but it seems it is!!
Check this link: [We're closing our Facebook features](http://support.twiends.com/entries/20204666-we-re-closing-our-facebook-features)

Comment: Ethically right, it doesn't involve ethics. Also, it is not illegal even it doesn't follow what Facebook wants you to do.

Comment: @Anush: I didn't fully understand what you said here.

Comment: It is not illegal or unethical.